# On a condition concerning the number of neighbors in bipartite graphs

Tags: graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

For any undirected simple graph $G=(V,E)$ we define for $v\in V$ the set $N(v) = \{w\in V: \{v,w\}\in E\}$.

Suppose $A, B$ are finite, disjoint sets, and $G = (A\cup B, E)$ is a bipartite graph with bipartition $(A,B)$ -- that is, for every $e\in E$ we have $e\cap A \neq \emptyset \neq e\cap B$. Informally speaking, I am trying to prove that if every $b\in B$ has "enough neighbors" in $A$, then $2$ members of $A$ "cover" $B$. More precisely, I would like to know whether the following statement is true:

> > If $N(b) > |A|/2$ for all $b\in B$, then there are $a_1, a_2\in A$ such that $N(a_1) \cup N(a_2) = B$.

Comment: AFAICT this is very probably not the intended meaning of the (covering) tag. Here is a related post on meta: [How should questions about (various meanings of) coverings be tagged?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3545)

Comment: Take $|A|=5$ and $|B|=10$, and connect each $b\in B$ with 3 elements of $A$, such that no two elements in $B$ have the same neighbourhood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong. Consider, for instance, the situation where the partite sets $A$ and $B$ are two copies of $\mathbb F_p$, with $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ prime, and $a\in A$ is adjacent to $b\in B$ whenever $a-b$ is a square in $\mathbb F_p$; that is, $a=b$ or $a-b$ is a quadratic residue. In this case each $b\in B$ has $(p+1)/2>|A|/2$ neighbors, but for any given $a_1,a_2\in A$ there are just about $\frac34p$ those $b\in B$ adjacent to either $a_1$ or $a_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Take some $N$.  Let $A=\lbrace a_j \mid 1\le j\le N\rbrace$ and $B=\lbrace b_{k\ell} \mid 1\le j,k\le N\rbrace$. Insert edges $\lbrace a_jb_{k\ell} \mid j\ne k,\ell\rbrace$. The degree of $b_{k\ell}$ is $|A|-2$. However, the combined neighbourhood of $a_j$ and $a_k$ does not include $b_{jk}$.  This shows that no constant less than 1 can replace $\frac12$ in the question.